# Expose return value

Tags: rest, handlebars.js, hapi.js, server-sent-events, eventsource

I have this piece of code that I am working on. To provide context, I am using an event source to stream an server sent event. Once I receive the data/response I want to pass that into my template(handlebars) view. The code below is a GET request in which I am trying to display the data returned from SSEvents.addEventListener.

```
method: 'GET',
path: '/students',
config: {
handler: (request, reply) => {
  SSEvents.addEventListener('score', function(e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    }, false);
      reply.view('students', {result: data});
   },
    description: "Endpoint lists all users that have received at least one test score.",
    tags: ['api']
   }
 }
```

The issue with this code is the constant "data" is not available outside of the scope of the event listener. I need to find a way to expose the constant so that I can use it in reply.view('students', {result: data});

NOTE: I have tried adding "reply.view('students', {result: data});" within the event listener and it throws the following error: reply interface called twice.

Any help would be appreciated.

--Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working like this. How long it takes your event source to produce an answer? Did you call the reply method twice? This is only one call.

```
handler: (request, reply) => {
        SSEvents.addEventListener('score', function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            return reply.view('students', {
                result: data
            });
        }, false);
    },
    description: "Endpoint lists all users that have received at least one test score.",
    tags: ['api']
}
```